# Can I just partially override __setattr__?

Tags: python

I'm imitating the behavior of the `ConfigParser` module to write a highly specialized parser that exploits some well-defined structure in the configuration files for a particular application I work with.  The files follow the standard INI structure:

```
[SectionA]
key1=value1
key2=value2

[SectionB]
key3=value3
key4=value4
```

For my application, the sections are largely irrelevant; there is no overlap between keys from different sections and all the users only remember the key names, never which section they're supposed to go in.  As such, I'd like to override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` in the `MyParser` class I'm creating to allow shortcuts like this:

```
config = MyParser('myfile.cfg')
config.key2 = 'foo'
```

The `__setattr__` method would first try to find a section called `key2` and set that to 'foo' if it exists.  Assuming there's no such section, it would look inside each section for a key called `key2`.  If the key exists, then it gets set to the new value.  If it doesn't exist, the parser would finally raise an `AttributeError`.

I've built a test implementation of this, but the problem is that I also want a couple straight-up attributes exempt from this behavior.  I want `config.filename` to be a simple string containing the name of the original file and `config.content` to be the dictionary that holds the dictionaries for each section.

Is there a clean way to set up the `filename` and `content` attributes in the constructor such that they will avoid being overlooked by my custom getters and setters?  Will python look for attributes in the object's `__dict__` before calling the custom `__setattr__`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pass `filename`, `content` to super class to handle it

```
class MyParser(object):
    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if k in ['filename', 'content']:
            super(MyParser, self).__setattr__(k, v)
        else:
                # mydict.update(mynewattr) # dict handles other attrs
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of having to maintain a list of these "special" attributes in the `__setattr__` method.  It looks like I can define these in the constructor using your `super` construction after which getting them works fine; `print config.filename` does the right thing.  Setting the attribute, however, doesn't work as it descends into the custom `__setattr__` and ends up throwing and error.  Why does python catch the attribute when getting, but not when setting?

Comment: If you don't want to define them in `__setattr__` then you could always define a class attribute instead (e.g. `MyParser.specials` instead of a literal list), but the flow of the code is the same. As to why getting works, isn't that just because `__getattr__` isn't defined in these examples?

Comment: @Cartroo I was actually referring to some testing I was doing on my own where I had indeed implemented those methods.  Turns out that it was because I had duplicated the logic of `__getattr__` where `return` statements ended execution of the code into `__setattr__` where those `return` statements now set variables without ending execution.  So the difference I had perceived was my bug rather than basic python behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be cleaner to present a dictionary-like interface for the contents of the file and leave attribute access for internal purposes. However, that's just my opinion.

To answer your question, `__setattr__()` is called prior to checking in `__dict__`, so you can implement it as something like this:

```
class MyParser(object):

    specials = ("filename", "content")

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr in MyParser.specials:
            self.__dict__[attr] = value
        else:
            # Implement your special behaviour here
```